# does anybody know how to link to a stylesheet in layout.phtml - zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm setting up my master layout.phtml file , but i can't seem to link to an external css  i've tried the normal link href ect but does not work i'm following the beginner' guide to ZF in the manaul is has the following:

```
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="/css/master.css" />
```

the manual also suggests putting these assets in the public folder which i have done. but does not work ?

I have also looked on the net and tried a some headlink and bootstrap stuff as a beginner it was a bit over my head !

Has anyone got a simple answer ??

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do as follows in layout.phtml:

```
<?php
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/css/master.css'));
echo $this->headLink();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the map hierarchy? on the page you're working on, is in that folder a folder css and in that folder the master.css?

Comment: i have main project folder zendy then the public folder inside the public folder i have css folder and then master.css ? the page im working on is the layout.phtml which is in /zendy/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml , thanks

Comment: So if i understand this correctly your layout.phtml is in:
`/zendy/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml `


and your master.css is in
`/zendy/public/css/master.css `?

Comment: try the following:

`<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="../../../public/css/master.css" />`

Comment: <?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/master.css') ?>